# How to export csv with coredata entries?

Tags: ios, swift, csv, core-data

I have an app that takes in user input that is stored in core data. To simplify things, I combined 5 strings from the user inputs, separated them with a comma and then this long string is stored in core data as 1 entity. The comma is separating the individual 'strings' is what makes it a CSV.

The tableview does what it's supposed to do, but the problem lies when I try to export the coredata entries as a csv. I realise that I am not making use of the fetchedStatsArray as I should and thus it is empty. I tried appending the array with NSManagedObject but none of that work. Is there a way to fix this, such that my fetchedStatsArray is filled? If not, is there another way to make sure that when the csv is generated, it will contain all the data from coredata?

Here is most of my code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import MessageUI

class HistoryController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    let cellId = "cellId"
    var fetchedStatsArray: [NSManagedObject] = []

    fileprivate lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<AlarmItem> = {
        //create fetch request
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<AlarmItem> = AlarmItem.fetchRequest()

        //configure fetch request
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "alarmAttributes", ascending: true)]
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

        let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

        let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

        fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

        return fetchedResultsController
    }()

    func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }

    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {

        switch(type) {
        case .insert:
            if let indexPath = newIndexPath {
                tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            }
            break;
        case .delete:
            if let indexPath = indexPath {
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            }
            break;
        case .update:
            //this is mostlikely where the problem lies
            //self.tableView.reloadData()
            if let indexPath = indexPath, let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
                configureCell(cell, at: indexPath)
            }
            break;
        case .move:
            if let indexPath = indexPath {
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            }
            if let newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
                tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .fade)
            }
            break;
        @unknown default:
            print("Something odd is happening")
        }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        do {
            try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        } catch let err as NSError {
            print("Failed to fetch items", err)
        }
    }

    @objc func addAlarmItem(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Add New Item", message: "Please fill in the blanks", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default) { [unowned self] action in

            //combined string of attributes
            let myStrings: [String] = alertController.textFields!.compactMap { $0.text }
            let myText = myStrings.joined(separator: ",")

            self.save(myText)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: nil)

        alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Enter Name of Engineer"
        }
        alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Enter Date of Alarm in DD/MM/YYYY"
        }
        alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Enter Time of Alarm in 24h (eg: 2300)"
        }
        alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Please indicate True/False (type True or False)"
        }
        alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Insert comments (if any), or NIL"
        }


        if let popoverController = alertController.popoverPresentationController {
            popoverController.sourceView = self.view;
            popoverController.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 0.0, height: 0.0)
            popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = []
            popoverController.barButtonItem = self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem
        }
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func save(_ itemName: String) {
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "AlarmItem", in: managedContext)!
        let item = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: managedContext)
        item.setValue(itemName, forKey: "alarmAttributes")

        do {
            try managedContext.save()
            tableView.reloadData()

        } catch let err as NSError {
            print("Failed to save an item", err)
        }
    }

    @objc func exportCSV(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        exportDatabase()
    }

    func exportDatabase() {
        let exportString = createExportString()
        saveAndExport(exportString: exportString)
    }

    func saveAndExport(exportString: String) {
        let exportFilePath = NSTemporaryDirectory() + "itemlist.csv"
        let exportFileUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: exportFilePath)
        FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: exportFilePath, contents: NSData() as Data, attributes: nil)
        var fileHandle: FileHandle? = nil

        do {
            fileHandle = try FileHandle(forUpdating: exportFileUrl as URL)
        } catch {
            print("filehandle has error")
        }

        if fileHandle != nil {
            fileHandle!.seekToEndOfFile()
            let csvData = exportString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)
            fileHandle!.write(csvData!)
            fileHandle!.closeFile()

            let firstActivityItem = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: exportFilePath)
            let activityViewController : UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [firstActivityItem], applicationActivities: nil)

            activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [
                UIActivity.ActivityType.assignToContact,
                UIActivity.ActivityType.saveToCameraRoll,
                UIActivity.ActivityType.postToFlickr,
                UIActivity.ActivityType.postToVimeo,
                UIActivity.ActivityType.postToTencentWeibo
            ]
            activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
            activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection()
            activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
            self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func createExportString() -> String {
        var alarmAttributes: String?
        var export: String = NSLocalizedString("Engineer Name,Date of Alarm,Time of Alarm,True or False,Engineer Comments \n", comment: "")

        for (index, AlarmItem) in fetchedStatsArray.enumerated() {
            if index <= fetchedStatsArray.count - 1 {
                alarmAttributes = AlarmItem.value(forKey: "alarmAttributes") as! String?
                let alarmAttributeStrings = alarmAttributes
                export += "\(alarmAttributeStrings ?? "0") \n"
            }
        }
        print("the app will now print: \(export) ")
        return export
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        let sectionInfo = fetchedResultsController.sections![section]
        return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
        let alarmItem = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath) as NSManagedObject
        cell.textLabel?.text = alarmItem.value(forKeyPath: "alarmAttributes") as? String
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView!, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard editingStyle == .delete else { return }

        //fetch
        let toBeDeleted = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)

        //delete
        fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext.delete(toBeDeleted)

        do {
            try fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch let err as NSError {
            print("failed to save item", err)
        }

    }

    func tableView(_tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AlarmItem", for: indexPath)
        configureCell(cell, at: indexPath)

        return cell
    }

    func configureCell(_ cell: UITableViewCell, at indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let alarmItem = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)

        //configure cell
        cell.textLabel?.text = alarmItem.value(forKeyPath: "alarmAttributes") as? String
    }
}
```

Comment: Why bother with an extra array, can't you use `fetchedObjects` on your `fetchedResultsController` object instead?

Comment: That was silly of me, thank you so much!!